# MLE for initial probability for Hidden Markov Model (supervised learning)

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, hidden-markov-model

Suppose I have a sequence of observations $\mathbf{o} = (o_1, ..., o_T)$ and a corresponding sequence of states natomiast $\mathbf{q} = (q_1, ..., q_T)$, where $q_i \in \{1,2,...,N\}$

Let $\mathcal{L}(A, B, \pi)$ be likelihood function of HMM $\lambda = (A, B, \pi)$
\begin{align}
    \mathcal{L}(A, B, \pi) = p(q_1)\prod\limits_{t=2}^Tp(q_t \mid q_{t-1})\prod\limits_{t=1}^Tp(\mathbf{o}_t 
    \mid q_t).
\end{align}

Then, log-likelihood function $\mathcal{\ell}$ is as follows
$$
    \mathcal{\ell} = \log\left[p(q_1)\prod\limits_{t=2}^Tp(q_t \mid q_{t-1})p(o_t 
    \mid q_t)\right] 
$$
So
$$
    \mathcal{\ell} = \log p(q_1) + \sum\limits_{t=2}^T \log p(q_t \mid q_{t-1}) +\sum\limits_{t=1}^T \log p(o_t \mid q_t)
$$

My question is: is it right to assume that initial distribution (part $\log p(q_1)$) follows a multinomial distribution (**shall I prove that somehow?**) and then simply get the MLE?

Comment: The initial distribution, for a classical HMM with discrete states, is a categorial distribution. Like multinomial but with a single trial.

Comment: @fm361 thank you. when I calculate MLE for categorical distribution I get $\pi_i = \frac{\mathbb{1}[q_1 = i]}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \mathbb{1}[q_1 = i]}$. So it seems I cannot estimate $\pi$ on the basis of the single sequence of observations. But what if I only have one sequence? I thought about estimating $\pi_i$ from a single sequence in the following way $\hat \pi_i =\frac{\text{# of observations from state i}}{\text{# of all observations}}$. But how to justify that?

Comment: Have you looked at the Baum-Welch algorithm? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Welch_algorithm

Comment: @fm361 of course, but I don't need BW algorithm when I know the underlying states. this is why I want to use explicit formulas derived from maximum likelihood approach.